# 'Has run' or 'was running' in 'His mother was running after the funeral'

Tags: word-choice

In the below mentioned paragraph, the author has written 'was running' in which should have been 'has run' because we use 'was running' when another incident has happened...

Please help to make it grammatically correct.
Or, she should write: his mother was running after the funeral when it was being carried.

> His mother **was running** after the funeral, singing lullaby for him, chanting songs for her beloved. The place of his burial was far but she might have prayed to run as long as her life. She gazed her son and the sun that was about to set. The green, black flags covered sky and the last rays of sun kissed Fahad.

Comment: Tip: try to make your titles [specific and informative](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187).

Answer (score 1):

No, it's perfectly normal English.

The rule in your book is a bit too strict. "While another event is happening" is not the only use of the continuous aspect.

The writer could have written "ran after the funeral" (not "has run", which would imply a present relevance, which is lacking).

The difference (as is often the case in the choice of aspect in English verb phrases) is in how the writer is choosing to depict the events. If they said "she ran after the funeral", that would be presenting it as a completed action. Choosing "she was running after the funeral" depicts it as a continuing action, setting the story while it was happening. These are both perfectly valid ways of talking about the same event, they just present them differently.